# issue getting the edit page to display in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, sql-server, codeigniter-2

For some reason I cannot for the life of me get the edit page to display. Not sure what I am doing wrong I went through the code so many times. When I click to edit a record the page is blank and no error messages come up.

here is the code for the model which I think is why it is causing an issue.

```
public function update_employee($data,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('employee_list',$data);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false:true;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the contoller

```
public function  update_employee()
    {
        $id=$this->input->post('id');

        $data=array('Employee_Name'=>$this->input->post('Employee_Name'),

            'Employee_Number'=>$this->input->post('Employee_Number'));


        $result=$this->employee_model->update_employee($data); 
if($result > 0) 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Employee Records Updated Successfully");
            redirect('employee/list_employees');

        }
        else
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"No changes Made in Employee Records");
            redirect('employee/list_employees');


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced return `($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false:true;`
with `return print_r($data);` and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Your function have a typo?

```
 $data=array('Emplyee_Name'...
```

Maybe it should be:

```
$data=array('Employee_Name'...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: that wasnt it I had type it to shorten down the code

Comment: sorry I had cut a few things in my code to shorten it down when I typed that i must have missed typed it. The issue still lies with the model  return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false:true;

Comment: return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false:true;  this has to be wrong

Comment: or could be in the controler not sure